# Probability of 1 object landing nearer than any other object to a control-object

Tags: probability

Say I have 3 colored cubes. 1 is white (the control-object), 1 is red, 1 is blue. I will scoop up all 3 cubes and drop them from my hand into a box top. What is the probability that the Blue cube will fall closer to the White cube than the Red cube does?

Additionally, I'm trying to determine how to increase/decrease the difficulty of achieving a result of the Blue cube being closer to the White cube when the Blue and/or Red cubes are increased in quantity.

Comment: What happens when the Blue cube will NOT fall closer to the White cube than the Red cube does? How many alternative situations? Can't you figure it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Basic approach.** Call the three cubes white, $A$, and $B$.  That is, we pretend we don't know which one of $A$ or $B$ is red, and which one is blue; either case is equally likely.  Under one of those cases, the condition is satisfied, and under the other, it is not.  Therefore, the probability in question is...?

Comment: Well, heck, when you simplify like that the answer becomes obvious. (sigh) My brain was over complicating it. Thanks. :) 50/50. For some reason, I was caught up on collision and bouncing around. Which, doesn't matter at all, now that I'm thinking clearly.